# Select from mysql table through variable Laravel

Tags: laravel

[image: Here uniname is the main data]

I want to select those `uniname` with same `seller_id`.There can be multiple `uniname` with same seller id. I am getting the seller_id info from html, where *seller_id* is passed as *id*. How to call it through controller for printing. The line I used is,

```php
$university = DB::table('universities')->where('seller_id', '$id');
```

```php
public function manage_seller_profile($id)
{
    $divisions = Division::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
    $districts = District::orderBy('id','asc')->get();
    $seller_profile = Seller_info::find($id);
    $university = DB::table('universities')->where('seller_id', '$id');
    
    return view('Backend.pages.seller.manage_seller_profile', compact('seller_profile', 'districts', 'divisions', 'university'));
}
```

Comment: remove single quote from variable '$id'.  $university = DB::table('universities')->where('seller_id', $id)->get();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to remove these single quotes, and add the Laravel ORM `select` and `get` functions.

Your code will look like this:

```
    $university = DB::table('universities')->where('seller_id', '=', $id)->select('uniname')->get();
```

I put the '=' operator to make the code more readable.